# How can I use this machine learning model on a new file without the output column?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I used some data from a csv file with 2 columns, first being comments and second being the outcome. I have got an output but would like to test this model on a file without the output column. How can I do it?

```
import csv

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

# review.csv contains two columns
# first column is the review content (quoted)
# second column is the assigned sentiment (positive or negative)
def load_file():
    with open('review.csv') as csv_file:
        reader = csv.reader(csv_file,delimiter=",",quotechar='"')
        reader.next()
        data =[]
        target = []
        for row in reader:
            # skip missing data
            if row[0] and row[1]:
                data.append(row[0])
                target.append(row[1])

        return data,target

# preprocess creates the term frequency matrix for the review data set
def preprocess():
    data,target = load_file()
    count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(binary='true')
    data = count_vectorizer.fit_transform(data)
    tfidf_data = TfidfTransformer(use_idf=False).fit_transform(data)

    return tfidf_data

def learn_model(data,target):
    # preparing data for split validation. 60% training, 40% test
    data_train,data_test,target_train,target_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(data,target,test_size=0.4,random_state=43)
    classifier = BernoulliNB().fit(data_train,target_train)
    predicted = classifier.predict(data_test)
    evaluate_model(target_test,predicted)

# read more about model evaluation metrics here
# http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html
def evaluate_model(target_true,target_predicted):
    print classification_report(target_true,target_predicted)
    print "The accuracy score is {:.2%}".format(accuracy_score(target_true,target_predicted))

def main():
    data,target = load_file()
    tf_idf = preprocess()
    learn_model(tf_idf,target)


main()
```

I got a result of 65%. Now how do I test this model On a new file without a output column and print the output to a new file

Comment: consider using pandas to read your file `import pandas as pd` and then `pd.read_csv('review.csv', error_bad_lines=False, names=['data', 'target'])` (quotechar and delimiter are default `'"'` and `','`.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `database` or `artificial-intelligence` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed & replaced with `scikit-learn`)

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to use Sklearn's [pipeline](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html)

Say you read your training data with the following:

```
def read_training(filename):
    # Read from a csv file with two columns. Skip bad lines
    df = pd.read_csv(
        filename,
        error_bad_lines=False,
        names=['data', 'target']
    )
    return df.data, df.target
```

You can do a similar thing for your new data. Make sure you have a file with a single column.

```
def read_test(filename):
    # Read from a csv file with a single column. Skip bad lines
    df = pd.read_csv(
        filename,
        error_bad_lines=False,
        names=['data']
    )
    return df.data
```

## Pipeline

You should then make your functions a little more dynamic using pipeline. See below code which is easy to read. It does not show the scoring steps as you showed.

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
import numpy as np

def main():
    # Read training file
    train_data, train_target = read_training('review.csv')

    # Prepare all sklearn functions in a single pipeline
    pipeline = Pipeline([
        ('count_vectorizer', CountVectorizer(binary='true')),
        ('tf_idf_transformer', TfidfTransformer(use_idf=False)),
        ('bernoulli_nb', BernoulliNB())        
    ])

    # This trains the entire pipeline on your training data
    pipeline.fit(train_data, train_target)

    # Your pipeline is now ready to apply to new data! 
    test_data = read_test('test.csv')
    prediction = pipeline.predict(test_data)

    # Write prediction to file
    np.savetxt("prediction.csv", prediction, delimiter=",", fmt="%s")
```

Comment: When I execute this, there seems to be quite a few errors. If you could guide and give exact solution, I would be grateful.

Comment: This is the error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/maniac/PycharmProjects/Test/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1434, in savetxt
    v = format % tuple(row) + newline
TypeError: must be real number, not numpy.str_

Comment: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/maniac/PycharmProjects/Test/Pandas", line 114, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/akshay/PycharmProjects/Test/Pandas", line 112, in main
    np.savetxt("prediction.csv", prediction, delimiter=",")
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in savetxt

Comment: File "/home/maniac/PycharmProjects/Test/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1438, in savetxt
    % (str(X.dtype), format))
TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('<U11') and format specifier ('%.18e')

Comment: All in the final `np.savetxt` appearently there are strings in your prediction. Please see updated answer and tell me if there's still something wrong